# PowerShell Question using Azure ARM Template Parameter array (my implementation of ConvertFrom-Json using an array fails)

Tags: json, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to pass in a $paramObject into a new ARM template deployment. I think I am missing something in my PowerShell to correctly convert the arrays so they can be used in the template.

```bsh
    $ResourceGroupName = "rg-testtemplate"
    New-AzResourceGroup -Name "rg-testtemplate" -Location "West US"

    $addressPrefixes = '["10.0.0.0/24"]' | ConvertFrom-Json
    $subnet = '[{"name":"default","properties":{"addressPrefix":"10.0.0.0/24"}}]' | ConvertFrom-Json

    $paramObject = @{
        'addressPrefixes' = $addressPrefixes
        'subnets' = $subnet
        'virtualNetworkName' = "vnet-testtemplate"
    }

    $parameters = @{
         'ResourceGroupName'     = $ResourceGroupName
         'TemplateFile'          = '.\testpowershell.json'
         'TemplateParameterObject'    = $paramObject
        'Verbose'               = $true
    }

    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
```

My template takes arrays.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "addressPrefixes": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "subnets": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type":  "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "location": "West US",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
        },
        "subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I go to deploy, I get back:

```
   New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 8:35:23 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Array'. Actual 'Object'. Please see
https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
At D:\repo\foldername\TestVM\testpowershelldeploy.ps1:30 char:5
+     New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At D:\repo\foldername\TestVM\testpowershelldeploy.ps1:30 char:5
+     New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

What is the "fix" for converting my Json to a PowerShell array that my template needs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an array object with PowerShell, please use the command `$t=@()` to create.

For example
My template.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "addressPrefixes": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "subnets": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type":  "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "location": "West US",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
        },
        "subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

my deploy script

```
Connect-AzAccount

$addressPrefixes =@( "10.0.0.0/24")
$subnet1= @{
       "name"= "default"
       "properties"=@{
                  "addressPrefix"="10.0.0.0/24"
        }

 }

$subnets = @($subnet1)

 $paramObject = @{
        'addressPrefixes' = $addressPrefixes
        'subnets' = $subnets
        'virtualNetworkName' = "vnet-testtemplate"
    } 

$parameters = @{
         'ResourceGroupName'     = "testtable"
         'TemplateFile'          = 'E:\test1.json'
         'TemplateParameterObject'    = $paramObject
        'Verbose'               = $true
    }

    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me to understand some of what is happening in my PowerShell script. However, the question goes more to how to provide a string conversion from the text I have, which is '["10.0.0.0/24"]' to the text you are suggesting, @( "10.0.0.0/24"). My question is attempting to ask .. is there a straightforward way to get PowerShell to hand me the Json string that the template expects, rather than the PowerShell object that breaks my deployment? My goal is to automate the conversion. I am asking because I have hundreds of these to do and my hand conversion is very error-prone.